# How to move marker slowly in latest google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-api-javascript-client

I am building a web application where one flight need to be fly from one place to another. I have build up airports and places aircrafts as marker now, how to move my aircrafts marker from one place to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve it by utilising the following:

```
  var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
    scale: 3, // change the size
    strokeColor: '#393'
  };
```

You will have to look into changing this yourself if you need an aeroplane etc..

You then need to implement the polyline for it to follow:

```
  // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{
      lat: 51.4700,
      lng: 0.4543
    }, {
      lat: 50.1109,
      lng: 8.6821
    }, {
        lat: 55.9533,
      lng: 3    
    }, {
      lat: 51.4700,
      lng: 0.4543
    },
    ],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 0, // change this value to show / hide the line
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }],
    map: map
  });

  animateCircle(line);
}
```

Finally, we need to add the method to animate the symbol on the line:

```
function animateCircle(line) {
  var count = 0;
  window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 1) % 200; // change this to 1000 to only show the line once
    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);
  }, 50); // change this value to change the speed
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/tu4s6302/3/

Comment: Though, I am curious about , when the path is not a straight line (say an arc) , how we will turn our arrow head on that path accordingly.

Comment: and I problem I came across is , we can't add custom image instead of arrow. any work around for this ?